# I have a java file with details to create a new camunda process, but when i create a new process i am getting the following error

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda, camunda-modeler

[image: Error while i start a new process in camunda]

```
@Autowired
private ProcessEngine camunda;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{scId}/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> placeOrderPOST(@PathVariable("scId") String scId) {
    ProcessContext context = new ProcessContext();
    submitShoppingCart(scId, context);
    if (context.getError() != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(context.getError(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(context.getResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);

}

private ProcessInstance submitShoppingCart(String scId, ProcessContext context) {
    return camunda.getRuntimeService().startProcessInstanceByKey(
            "submitShoppingCart", 
            Variables 
                    .putValue(ProcessConstants.VAR_SC_ID, scId).putValue(ProcessConstants.VAR_CTX, context));
}
```

**CMD ERROR**

2021-06-20 13:31:59.252 ERROR 11368 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[Engine Api]           : Servlet.service() for servlet [Engine Api] in context with path [] threw exception [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById(SimpleJpaRepository.java:223) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.7.RELEASE]

**Above is the code to create new instance, what should i give in the business key and what variable values should i give to start the instance?**

Comment: I think you need to provide some variables If you are trying to start the process from cockpit. It is failing somewhere in your process execution.

Comment: where can i find those values?any idea

Comment: You are starting the process from your rest API or camunda cockpit?

Comment: camunda cockpit.when i post the same from postman it is giving me the correct response.But when i create a new process from the camunda tasklist i am getting error.

Comment: Ok. Check that when you are starting your process from your rest API, you are providing some variable. The same you need to provide from cokpti as key value pair. I am seeing that you are providing these variables putValue(ProcessConstants.VAR_SC_ID, scId).putValue(ProcessConstants.VAR_CTX, context));

Comment: Okay.Thank you Rahul, will try providing those variables.